# TypeError: (intermediate value).keys(...).map is not a function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am getting a strange error, could somebody help me fix this out?

```
const myArray = new Array(4)
    .keys()
    .map((v, i) => (
          console.log('print:', v, i)
      )
    )
console.log('myArray print: ', myArray);
```

I am getting this error:

```
TypeError: (intermediate value).keys(...).map is not a function
```

### update:

i want to use the `i` to look up some stuff from another existing array.

```
const myArray = new Array(4)
    .keys()
    .map((v, i) => ({
      name: i
      })
    )
console.log('myArray print: ', myArray);
```

### edit:

this question is not a duplicate, It is trying to iterate over a certain number and create a new object using the iterations.

Comment: the function keys when applied to the array returns an object, and the map function is not available for objects.

Comment: What do you want to do with the code above?

Comment: Same issue and solution as the dupe target, except that `keys` is an iterator object instead of a HTML collection.

Comment: You can use `entries()` instead of `map()`

Comment: @Faly please see the update

Comment: @Alexis can you give an example?

Comment: Reopened question since it is not a duplicate of the linked question.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫: How is it not a duplicate? It's the ___same issue___: Array-like return value that isn't an array. It's got the ___same solution___.

Comment: @Cerbrus Not really. An iterator from an array with unindexed `undefine`s is fundamentally different than a live list. They might both yield the same error message, but they are different issues and require different answers.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫: `Array.from(new Array(4).keys())` or `[...new Array(4),keys()]` works just fine. (From the dupe target)

Comment: @Cerbrus Different answers as in different explanation. It just so happens that `Array.from` accepts both an iterator and a live list because they are both array-like. A rule of thumb is that a question is a duplicate if you can copy and paste an answer from the linked question without having to modify and it remains a valid answer.

Comment: And that's exactly my point. It's about converting array-like objects to the arrays a users expected them to be in the first place. It may not be the best dupe target, but I'm sure there's one out there.

Comment: "they are both array-like" uhm no. Please don't say array or even something in that direction to an iterator. It is a different thing. The close-dupe here is not justified imo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use *Array.from* to get the expected output:

```js
var myArray = Array.from(Array(4), (value, index) => ({ name: index}));
console.log('myArray print: ', myArray);
```

Answer (score 4):

[Array.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/keys) returns an iterator Object which is an object and does not have a property map in it. You can convert it to do

```js
const myArray = [...new Array(4).keys()].map((v, i) => ({
      name: i
      })
    )
console.log('myArray print: ', myArray);
```

Comment: Solution: Just pass it through `Array.from`

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 can you please give an example?

Comment: @moaningalways `Array.from(something.keys()).map`

Comment: Or you can do `[...new Array(4).keys()].map((v, i) => v)`

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 could you please provide an answer with a working example? thanks

Comment: @moaningalways I believe that comment is more than enough to get you started.

Comment: This answer does not deserve some upvotes because it only explains the problem. It however does not provide an answer to the OP's problem.

Comment: @KarelG the original question was why does it not work which is answered